# A: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0) error when addGestureRecognizer to UILable which is created by storyboard in swift3

Tags: ios, swift

I create a `UILable` which name is `addFont`, and `addGestureRecognizer` manually to it, but there comes a unfamiliar `error`:

`EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)`

my code is below:

`vc9:`

```
 @IBAction func gotoVC(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    var vc10 = ViewController10()
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc10, animated: true)
}
```

`vc10:`

```
@IBOutlet weak var addBigger: UILabel!
var fontSizeNum:Int = 22
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    initData()
}

// MARK: - init
func initData() -> Void {

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(addFont(sender:)))
    addBigger.addGestureRecognizer(tap) // the error occured
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So! after many thinks, i finally found that the `vc9`'s code:`var vc10 = ViewController10()`  it create a `vc10` not from `storyboard`, so the `addBigger` label is nil, it is the error's source.

The solution is :

change `var vc10 = ViewController10()` to

```
let sb = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc10 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController10")
```